# What does MSSL sampling refers to?

Tags: statistics, sampling

In a document I came across this sentence "calculation of MSSL using fixed and dynamic methods". The document itself is about sampling techniques and no other explanation is given there. I tried to google MSSL and I just end up in companies, clubs etc... that theire name abbriviates in MSSL!

Would you kindly tell me what MSSL refers to in mathematics, and how can I get more info over this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it happend to be MaximumSkipSamplesLimit